# how to replace full part of the input from the user

Tags: python

How can I change part of the input in Python? for example, if the user writes down: "I like to eat hot food" or "I want to eat junk food" etc, all the parts "eat... food", no matter what there is between them, will change into "running" so the output became "I like to running", "I want to running".
Thank you.

Edit: this is my first post so I still learning. try again:

in the meantime I have this:

```
  def eat_food(s):
        if "eat" and "food" in s:
            return s.replace( ? , "running")
        else:
            return s
```

what I need is this:

```
 input ("I want to eat junk food")
    output = "I want to running"
    or
    input ("I like to eat hot food")
    output = "I like to running"
```

hope now it's more clear

Comment: how do you determine what to change? will it always be `eat ... food`?

Comment: `re.sub("eat.+?food", "running", "I want to eat junk food")`

Comment: Matiiss, yes. if the user wrote eat.... food, no matter what inside, it needs to be changed.

Comment: @OlvinRoght again, your answer is good if I know what I get in the input...

Comment: @AviAd you want me to guess?

Comment: @OlvinRoght if I get input with the words "eat bla bla bla food" I need all this part to change into running, and I need to tell Python that every time I get a sentence with "eat" and after it "food" it must change. now it's more clear?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AviAd you didn't even bothered to copy one damn line of code and try to apply it but complaining about it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght sorry this is my first post and I'm learning Python for two weeks, so it's all-new for me. made edit again :)

Comment: @AviAd no, really, code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71519125/10824407#comment126406717_71519125) comment is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a task like this you need to use a "regular expression".
It lets you define a template like "everything between words eat and food" and then search the text for that template.

To start, import the regular expression module in to your program:

```
import re
```

In regular expression '.' (dot) means match every letter, and '*' (asterisk) means match zero or more times.

So, you want a regex like this: `'eat.*food'` which means match "eat" then zero or more of any character, than "food".

To replace what you found use the function `sub` from the `re` module:

```
def eat_food(s):
    return re.sub('eat.*food', 'running', s)

answer = input('What do you like?')

print(eat_food(answer))
```

Some things to note:

1. String in Python are immutable - meaning you `sub` will return a new string with the replacement, not change your existing one.
2. If the user inputs "I like to ..." you should replace it with "run" not "running" for correct English grammar.

Comment: Now try with `I want to eat junk food I'm tired of seafood`. Use lazy match.

Comment: @OlvinRoght the output is `I want to running` which is what the OP stated he wanted the output to be. With a lazy match the output will be `I want to running I'm tired of seafood` which does not match the required output example as stated in question and also does not make much sense as a sentence... If you think lazy match is a better solution to this question, why not make your comment in to a proper answer? The OP states he is new at this, so it would be really helpful to explain what the code is doing and why.

Comment: I am trying to avoid giving answer to questions which could be solved using oneliner. Anyway, your answer contains descent explanations, which is good. I've tried to point that lazy match is semi-stable solution. E.g. `I want to eat junk food. I want to eat healthy food.`